# Error while using pdfbox to create pdf : Identifier expected after this token

Tags: java, eclipse, pdfbox, eclipse-juno, java-6

I am working on a plain Java project in eclipse juno using jre6/jdk6 as runtime/compiler.  I wish to use apache pdfbox to generate some pdfs. i have [downloaded](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/pdfbox/1.8.9/pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar) and added pdfbox 1.8.9 to my build path. now i took a code sample from [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/documentcreation.html), and used it in my application, but it is giving me multiple error which i think is related to some environment problems.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
public class TestPdf {

PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
// Create a new blank page and add it to the document
PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
document.addPage( blankPage );
// Save the newly created document
document.save("BlankPage.pdf");
// finally make sure that the document is properly
// closed.
document.close();
}
```

These are the errors i am getting :

```
Syntax error on token "blankPage", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
Syntax error on token ""BlankPage.pdf"", delete this token
Syntax error on token "close", Identifier expected after this token
```

Comment: These seem Javac errors!

Comment: i too think that @Raffaele, but how to correct ?

Comment: @SubhamTripathi See my answer and let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a method and move some of the code inside the method :

```
public class TestPdf {

    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    // Create a new blank page and add it to the document
    PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();

    public void createDocument()throws Exception {
        document.addPage(blankPage);
        // Save the newly created document
        document.save("BlankPage.pdf");
        // finally make sure that the document is properly
        // closed.
        document.close();
    }
}
```

The code that you posted in your question is against the syntax rules of the Java language. You can read more about the structure of a class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: ya this worked for me. but why was it not working earlier can you please shed some light over it ?

Comment: This is a very common mistake developers make when they write code in a hurry. Your code did not work because the code that I moved to the createDocument method is not allowed to be declared without an enclosing method, static block or instance block. That's the Java syntax for you and you can't go against the syntax of a language. I believe I have answered your question so don't forget to click the tick and upvote :)

Comment: will click the tick for sure ... thanks for helping :)